# Should multiplicity be addressed when doing preliminary examination of missingness?

Tags: missing-data, multiplicity

When dealing with missing data, one recommended initial step is to examine the effect of the missingness in each variable on the other variables. This entails doing multiple tests where a significant finding means that the data in the variable are not missing completely at random (MCAR). My question is, should a multiplicity correction be applied in this scenario? Obviously, the experimenter would rather deal with MCAR and doing a correction would increases the chances of that, but is this justifiable?

Answer (score 0):

No, there should not be a multiplicity correction.

Recall that if we perform two independent hypothesis tests and the null hypothesis is true for both of them, the probability that we incorrectly reject the null hypothesis at 0.05 on at least one of the tests is 0.0975, much higher than the intended confidence level. Multiplicity corrections adjust for that so that the total probability of a false positive is 0.05 (or whatever the desired alpha is). This decreases the probability of finding a true positive (power) in exchange for controlling the probability of finding false positives.

But in testing for MCAR, the primary concern is not false positives. If the data is truly MCAR and the test rejects that (false positive) then the analyst will have to do more work, possibly use a more robust method, and the results will probably have reduced power. On the other hand if the data is truly MAR or MNAR and the analyst incorrectly determines the data is MCAR (false negative) there could be serious biases in the results. As the analyst will believe the data is MCAR they may feel comfortable trusting the results and make a serious error.

Therefore, as there is larger risk in false negatives than false positives when doing MCAR tests, there should not be a multiplicity correction.